# Child component doesn't update when parent updates

Tags: reactjs, redux

When I add a new product to the products array using the `addQuantityButton` function via the child component, the change to the products array isn't recognised in the child Product component.  `addQuantityButton`function in the parent component is correctly adding a new object to the array.  This stopped working when I started using Redux and mapStateToProps. What am I doing wrong here?

Path: `Parent`

```
class Form extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      products: [getNewProduct()]
    };

    this.addQuantityButton = this.addQuantityButton.bind(this);
  }

  addQuantityButton(product_id) {
    let { products } = this.state;

    products = products.map((product) => {
      if (product.product_id === product_id) {
        product.quantities.push(getNewQuantity());

        return product;
      }
      return product;
    });

    this.setState({
      products
    });
  }

  render() {
    const { products } = this.state;
    return (
      <form>
        {products.map((product) => (
          <Product
            key={product.key}
            product_id={product.product_id}
            quantities={product.quantities}
            addQuantityButton={this.addQuantityButton}
          />
        ))}
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

Path: `Product`

```
class Product extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      unitOptions: []
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          {this.props.quantities.map((quantity) => (
            <p>Example</p>
          ))}
        </div>

        <button
          type="button"
          onClick={() => addQuantityButton(this.props.product_id)}
        >
          Add quanity
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

Product.propTypes = {
  product_id: PropTypes.string,
  quantities: PropTypes.array,
  addQuantityButton: PropTypes.func
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  supplierProducts: state.product.products
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Product);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

child is listening to redux's state, which is different from parent's state. react component state is one thing, redux state is other. copying redux's state to a component's state is not advisable, you are duplicating state.

I would suggest at Parent's to map only your products to props, then iterate at your form as `this.props.products.map(...`

while at Children you declare a `mapDispatchToProps` responsible to increment the quantity. there you declare your `addQuantityButton` with some refactors. you will use dispatch instead which receives an action. the logic to add product will be implemented at your reducer down the road.

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, ownProps) => ({
  addQuantityButton: dispatch(addQuantity(ownProps.product_id))
})
```

your action is a simple function declared at some actions file, that return an object containing the action TYPE and a payload (you could call the payload something else fwiw):

```
const addQuantity = product_id => ({
  type: 'ADD_QUANTITY',
  payload: product_id
})
```

now, dispatch with a proper action will pass down the object to reducers, and a given reducer that intercepts `ADD_QUANTITY` will be responsible to increment quantity, and that way return next redux state.

at reducer you implement the logic to update state.

```
function productsReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'ADD_QUANTITY': // suggestion, declare your types as a constant in another file
      // also, dont mutate state directly!, you may need to use some deep clone given it's an array of objects 
       return // logic here with action.payload and state.products
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```